# What's the nearest neighbor algorithm used for upsampling?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, interpolation

> Additionally, by default, the UpSampling2D layer will use a **nearest neighbor algorithm** to fill in the new rows and columns. This has the effect of simply doubling rows and columns, as described and is specified by the ‘**interpolation**‘ argument set to ‘nearest‘. Alternately, a **bilinear interpolation** method can be used which draws upon multiple surrounding points. This can be specified via setting the ‘interpolation‘ argument to ‘bilinear‘.

How exactly does the **nearest neighbor** algorithm mentioned above work? Also, what does **interpolation** mean in this context (***nearest*** and ***bilinear***)?

Source: [Section on Upsampling2D layer](https://machinelearningmastery.com/upsampling-and-transpose-convolution-layers-for-generative-adversarial-networks/)

Comment: Interpolation typically means that you compute the value for a position/unit $x$ based on its "surrounding" positions/units. I would need to read that article to give a formal answer.